# How do you assign different values to the href element of NavLink in Chakra Navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I want to give the `href` element in the `NavLink` component as the value of the `Links` array. Can I give a value to `href` using the map function?

To be clear, I would like to give the `href` elements of the `NavLink` function the values of 'Home', 'Projects', and 'Careers'. (Not "#")

Link array

```
const Links = ['Home', 'Projects', 'Careers'];
```

NavLink function

```
const NavLink = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => (
  <Link
    px={2}
    py={1}
    rounded={'md'}
    _hover={{
      textDecoration: 'none',
      bg: useColorModeValue('#00afff', '#00afff'),
    }}
    href={'#'}
  >
    {children}
  </Link>
);
```

Components Used

```
<HStack spacing={8} alignItems={'center'}>
  <NavBarLogo src= {HdhLogo} />
  <HStack
    as={'nav'}
    spacing={4}
    display={{ base: 'none', md: 'flex' }}>
    {Links.map((link) => (
      <NavLink key={link}>{link}</NavLink>
    ))}
  </HStack>
</HStack>
```

Comment: you can give links as a prop `const NavLink = ({ children,links })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Links` array is an array of strings

```
const Links = ['Home', 'Projects', 'Careers'];
```

that are passed as children

```
{Links.map((link) => (
  <NavLink key={link}>
    {link}
  </NavLink>
))}
```

Just pass the `children` prop to the `href` prop

```
const NavLink = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => (
  <Link
    px={2}
    py={1}
    rounded={'md'}
    _hover={{
      textDecoration: 'none',
      bg: useColorModeValue('#00afff', '#00afff'),
    }}
    href={children}
  >
    {children}
  </Link>
);
```

It may be better to expose an `href` prop on the `NavLink` component though.

```
const NavLink = ({ children, href }: { children: ReactNode, href: string }) => (
  <Link
    px={2}
    py={1}
    rounded={'md'}
    _hover={{
      textDecoration: 'none',
      bg: useColorModeValue('#00afff', '#00afff'),
    }}
    href={href}
  >
    {children}
  </Link>
);
```

...

```
{Links.map((link) => (
  <NavLink key={link} href={link}>
    {link}
  </NavLink>
))}
```